# How to change the trim width from booktabs for the full table at once?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I often end up adjusting all trim lengths of `cmidrule` in a table to the same non-default value. The only option I found in the [booktabs documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) is to adjust every single `l` and `r` marker of every `cmidrule` manually, as in `\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){1-1}`.

Is there a way I can do this for a whole table at once without mindlessly copy-pasting everything 100 times?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\cmidrule(r{1pt}){1-1}
\cmidrule(l{1pt}r{1pt}){2-2}
\cmidrule(l{1pt}){3-3}
Cat & Dog & Mouse \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation (page 4) says that `l` is the same as `l{\cmidrulekern}` and that the default value of `\cmidrulekern` is `0.5em`.

Actually, it would be better if instead of a dimen register it was a macro, so the value of em is computed at run time and not in the document preamble, which might refer to the em of a font not used in the document or, at least, it was set at begin document.

Anyway, you can do in your preamble (or in the environment where you need the changed setting)

```
\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{1pt}
```

Comment: Thanks, no idea how I managed to not see that in the documentation, but I guess if somebody else ever has the same problem they at least have something to google now.